# Import Source Archive in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I have received an entire source archive for a Yocto-build. But I can't figure out how to install it.
The archive is a zip file containing three .tar.xz files with names like `machine-name-allarch-poky-linux.tar.xz`, where each of these files contain a directory structure like `sources/allarch-poky-linux/` followed by many different folders with all different source packages.

The file structure is just like what can be found here:
https://download.automotivelinux.org/AGL/release/lamprey/12.1.0/raspberrypi4/deploy/sources/

As in above, the final directories contain a .tar.gz with all source code etc for each package, and very often there is also a couple of patches and other miscellaneous files.

Probably the archive was created with the [archiver class](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#providing-the-source-code).
But the manual does not say anything about what the user (in this case, me) shall do to install the created archive.
It seems to be related to the DL_DIR, but the file structure doesn't really comply with what the DL_DIR usually contains (only tarballs, no loose patches etc. and the tarballs are not in sub-directories as in the archive).

How do I go about to get Yocto to use these archives?

Comment: Is that the zip of DL_DIR?

Comment: What do you mean by "get Yocto to use these archives"? The archive is simply a dump of all the source code for packages built by that Yocto build. It does not include Yocto metadata that you can use to replicate the build using `bitbake`